# how to play an open Bm on the 7th fret of the guitar

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I am trying to work out what the chords are to a song by the band Oasis which uses an **open string Bm** chord up on the 7th fret but I can't figure out the fingering. I know how to play a Bm chord as a barre chord but I want to learn this version of it. Can anyone please help with some possible fingerings of the chord?

Here is a link to the video

and you can see the chord at 1:21

Comment: Presumably you've already noticed he's not in standard tuning?

Comment: Nope, never noticed that but that E chord he plays seems like a pretty standard E chord shape so if you could please tell me why you think he is not using standard tuning

Comment: Ah, now I'm awake… he's just got his thumb over the top of the neck.

Comment: ok so thumb plays B on 7th fret?

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't look like the thumb is doing any pressing down... what about it maybe being a 2nd inversion Bm chord so in other words no bottom string?

Answer (score 4):

it's more of a Bm add4 (or add11).

*fingering:*
with thumb to mute: `x99700`
with thumb to fret: `799700`

and, of course, that can be tactically muted/strummed to mute the *e* at the top, making it a straight *Bm* too and giving a little melodic interplay between the *d* (7th fret g string) and *e* (open e string) at the top of the chord.  Their spacing apart (separated by the open b) makes it not too tricky to target these notes and highlight them while strumming, which is what your man does here.

To mute the ringing e string entirely for a straight Bm chord, you can let the inside of your left hand fingers touch the bottom of the guitar neck.  You don't have to, but if you want to it's a good tip for how.

Abcjs transcription of the 4 possibilities just for fun:

```
X: 1
T: 
M: 4/4
L: 8/8
R: 
K: Bmin
%%annotationfont Times-Italic *
|"^no thumb" "_Bm add4/F#"[FBBde]| "^thumb""_Bm add4"[B,FBBde]|"^muted top w/o thumb""_Bm/F#"[FBBd]| "_Bm""^muted top w/ thumb" [B,FBBd]|
```

the first is the one most employed here

Answer (score 3):

Simply play an open E minor shape at 9 (and 7 fret on 3rd string). There's an open top string sounding too.The open B string will be in tune! Bottom string is up to you - maybe thumb over, or leave it out.